# Trying to install MySQL but getting (The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden)

Tags: installation, mysql, database

I'm trying to download the following MySQL Products but getting the same results as shown in the following figure and script. I tried to search but no similar problem with the same situation appeared.

[image]

```
    https://updates.oracle.com/Orion/Services/download/p27197679_100_MSWIN-x86-64.zip?aru=21759870&patch_file=p27197679_100_MSWIN-x86-64.zip
1: Download of package 'MySQL Server 5.7.21' failed with message The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
2: Download of package 'MySQL For Excel 1.3.7' failed with message The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
3: Download of package 'MySQL Enterprise Backup 4.1.0' failed with message The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
4: Download of package 'MySQL Utilities 1.6.5' failed with message The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
5: Download of package 'MySQL Shell 1.0.11' failed with message The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
```

Your fast response will help a lot. Thank you

Comment: I get "401 Authorization Required" for this URL. It is a specific problem with Oracle, did you use the correct credentials? More important, since you pay them for this service: did you contact them?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Do you think that this problem related to payment issues? I'm still remember if I payed for this or not?

Comment: I have no idea what you paid or not to Oracle. Why not contacting them?